# How to presentViewController without use Seque

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna present a collectionView after I do some search from the tableView and tap the cell.

I create a searchController which is also a tableViewController and implement the updateSearchResultsForSearchController(), it works well and display the result I want.

Since storyboard hasn't got a searchController, I can't create a segue between the searchController and the collectionViewController.What I tried is

```
//PostListId is the storyboard id of postList(collectionview here)
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Choose the viewController I wanna display
    let postList = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PostListId") as! PostListController
    // Send data to collectionView 
    postList.key = 1
    // PresentViewController
    self.presentViewController(postList, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But when I tap the cell after search, I got a error here, and no error messages feedback, Why?

Comment: You can use a storyboard scene if you want. Just set the view controller custom type appropriately

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
let postCtrl = PostListController() //create instance of your controller 
postCtrl.key = 1
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: postCtrl) //create navigation controller if you want
pushViewController(navigationController, animated: true) //display
```

or you can present your controller as modal if you prefer:

```
presentViewController(postCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine as of now. Make sure you set the storyboard id:

[image]